# Can I detach an existing cdb.exe?

Tags: debugging, windbg, adplus

Scenario:
Our program launches adplus at startup to monitor for crashes.
So there is a cdb.exe process running.

At some point we want to detach cdb.exe but leave the program running.

Is there any way to do this?  There is no UI for the cdb process.

I'm looking for some sort of way to do this from the command line.

Currently if we kill cdb, it also kills our process.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's simply the `-lcqd` command line option, which causes the last command to be `qd`.

If that's not what you want, you can let AdPlus generate the script it's using with the `-gs` switch

```
adplus -crash -o T:\ -gs
```

When you have the switch, you can add

```
.ocommand LetMeTakeControl
```

as the last but one command (just before `g`). You'd then run `cdb` with the `-cf` command line switch and run that script.

Then, from your application, use

```
OutputDebugString("LetMeTakeControl qd");
```

to quit and detach.